# I am looking for Chinese equivalent for Lato font

Tags: font-recommendation

I am looking for a Chinese font that would give the page the same look and feel as the Lato font does for Latin and Cyrilic languages.

Anybody a suggestion where to look how to start?
Thank you

Comment: I don't know if it is here but you can try to find on this site.
http://www.dafont.com/

Answer (score 5):

### Noto Sans

Give Noto Sans a try, it's *"similar"* to the the style found in Lato, unfortunately Lato does not support Chinese at the moment, but Nato Sans support both Traditional Chinese and Simplified Chinese.

**This is the Nato Sans (Traditional) Chinese Character Set:**

[image]

**Below is a picture with both fonts (Latin) as a comparison:**

[image]